# What difference with them? '!arr.length' and 'arr.length=0'

Tags: javascript, arrays

What difference with them? '!arr.length' and 'arr.length=0'

i can't understand well :(

```
let arr = [] ;

!arr.length 

arr.length = 0
```

Really appreciate it, if you explain it logically. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Do you mean `arr.length === 0` or `arr.length = 0`? Because `arr.length = 0` removes all the items from the array and nothing to do with `!arr.length`

Comment: do you mean arr.length == 0?

Comment: i maen arr.length =0 :)  but if it is arr.length === 0 , what different that ?

Comment: Strange comparison indeed. Typically you would want to know the difference between `!arr.length` and `arr.length === 0`

Comment: array.length does not empty the array. It's a read only property and setting it to 0 has no effect on the array @adiga

Comment: @AjithGopi That's incorrect. It WILL empty the array.

Comment: @codemonkey Oh, my bad.. it does empty the array

Comment: @adiga, Sorry you are right :) learnt something new today.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are completely different.

`!arr.length` will evaluate to true if the array has no items. It will evaluate to false if the array has items.

`arr.length = 0` will clear the array, removing all its items, and evaluate to 0.

Comment: I would like to add a point that !arr.length will be evaluated to true because: the value of arr.length will be converted to Boolean during this expression. And any number except 0 will be converted to true.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean:

```
let arr = [] ;

!arr.length // true, because 0 ~ false and !false == true

arr.length == 0 // true
```

Note the double equals.

The difference is this:

```
let arr = 3;

!arr.length // true, because undefined ~ false, and !false == true

arr.length == 0 // false
```

If the "array" could be something other than an array (for example, you get it as data from a remote system across an API boundary), then if it does not have a length property, your first test will not return the result you want.